# Navigation Drop-Down Menu: Pull from List

Tags: navigation

Is it possible to create a drop-down menu (on global navigation, top bar) which would pull its links from a sharepoint list? We are trying to create a drop-down menu which would incorporate security trimming. For instance, if an individual does not have access to a particular site, we would like that site to not appear under the drop-down menu.

We think we can do this in a list, but we need to create a link between that list and a drop-down menu.

Edit: I'm on SP 2010 :(

Comment: Technically possible, slightly complicated. You need to code something in either javascript or C#.

Comment: Do you have Managed Metadata? Is this 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SharePoint 2013, you can build a Managed Metadata term set that will define global navigation. If you actually want it to be a list, however, or if you're using a previous version of SharePoint, you have to build a custom Global Navigation Provider in Visual Studio. The process of doing that is far too complicated to go through here, but here are some links to get you started:

- Building metadata navigation in 2013 is covered [here](http://www.mavention.com/blog/building-global-navigation-sharepoint-2013) by Mavention
- Somnath Matere explains how to build your own navigation provider [on his blog](http://somnathmatere.blogspot.com/2011/05/creating-custom-navigation-provider-in.html)
- There are some 3rd-party solutions available on Codeplex, like [SP Navigation Menu](http://spnavigationmenu.codeplex.com/)

Each option has its pros & cons, but you can decide which is the best option for your needs. Both of the second options use a SP list to define the global navigation.

Comment: So much for asking if he is using 2013 and if he has access to Managed Metadata beforehand in a comment :P  Oh well +1

Comment: @eirikb : Sorry - I'm still fairly new here so I'm probably not up to snuff on all the etiquette yet.

Comment: It's no problem. In all honesty you could say I was just lazy, it's not like we should let lazy people like me "hold off" answers like that :) And your answer is a good one, much better than I would have come up with